# Enums "ghost values": what for?

Tags: c++, enums

I have recently noticed a fact that was to me quite surprising:
you apparently can retrieve any arbitrary value from an `enum` type and assign it to an `enum` variable even if it is not part of the `enum` definition (what I call a "ghost value"). The variable simply takes the corresponding integer value.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

enum myEnumType { ONE = 1, TWO = 2, THREE = 3 };

int main () {

    myEnumType e;

    e=myEnumType(8);

    std::cout << e << std::endl;

}
```

which outputs `8`.

I would have thought this wasn't possible, as it seems to me at odds with the constraining function of enumerated types.
**What is the reason and, most importantly, the possible utility of this?**

Comment: `e=myEnumType(8);` effectively resembles `e=(myEnumType)8;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were allowed to cast an `int` to an `enum`. C++11 introduced "enumeration classes" or "strong enums" or "scoped enums" to deal with this among other problems.

Other benefits include their scope and allowing forward declaration.

There are lots of details on [Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#enum)'s page and he specifically mentions three problems with the traditional enums:

- conventional enums implicitly convert to int, causing errors when someone does not want an enumeration to act as an integer.
- conventional enums export their enumerators to the surrounding scope, causing name clashes.
- the underlying type of an enum cannot be specified, causing confusion, compatibility problems, and makes forward declaration impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling to constructor of the enum passing 8, so the value assigned to that instance  is 8.

It happens the same thing when you call to enum default constructor, it sets 0 as default value.

```
myEnumType e = myEnumType();
std::cout << e << std::endl; // prints 0
```

[It prints 0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/30a86b3adea40ac9) (although the enum is only initialized with ONE = 1, TWO = 2, THREE = 3), here it is better explained: http://lifecs.likai.org/2010/07/c-enum-default-constructor.html